# Troubles with linked list - why aren't new elements being added to my list?

Tags: c

My linked list print function keeps printing only one value and I can't figure out why. Everything works as expected.

Here is the struct that I store in linked list:

```
typedef struct list_element {
    int value;
    struct list_element *next;
} list_element;
```

These are the functions to operate on list:

```
list_element createNewLinkedList()
{
    list_element *myElement = (list_element *) malloc(sizeof(list_element));
    myElement->value = 0;
    myElement->next = NULL;
    return *myElement;
}

int insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list_element element, int value)
{
    list_element *myElement = &element;
    do {
        if (myElement->next == NULL) {
            list_element *new = (list_element *)malloc(sizeof(list_element));
            new->value = value;
            new->next = NULL;
            myElement->next = new;
        } else {
            myElement = myElement->next;
        }

    } while (myElement->next != NULL);
}

int printListValues(list_element firstNode)
{
    list_element *temp = &firstNode;
    int sentinel = 1;
    while (sentinel) {
        printf(" %d,", temp->value);
        if (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        } else {
            sentinel = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the function that prints only first value, 100:

```
void checkLinkedList()
{
    list_element list = createNewLinkedList();
    list.value = 100;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        int value = rand();
        insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list, value);
    }
    printListValues(list);
}
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function

```
int insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list_element element, int value)
```

is accepting a list_element object, meaning, a copy of the head of your list, what you want to pass is a pointer, so:

```
int insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list_element *element, int value)
```

and this way you add the value to the actual list and not a copy of it.

You need to learn to use pointers, and use a debugger to check where your data stays.

Comment: Yup. That and the fact that you do the same thing everywhere, including the allocation...

Comment: I have changed them to pointers and also there was a logic error in insertNew element - the doWhile part failed on second element - and everything works. Thanks! I guess I am spoiled by objective-c where everything is a pointer.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I hate Java, the everything is a pointer routine is not something I'm used to